# Compare a key in a map with every string in a list and if they match then store it inside a new map with its corresponding value from the old map

Tags: scala, list, hashmap

**For example:**

The map is given below:

> output = Map(execution -> 1, () -> 2, for -> 1, in -> 1, brutalized -> 1, everyone -> 1, felt -> 1, christ -> 1, all -> 1, saw -> 1, crying -> 1, it -> 1, two -> 1, a -> 2, man -> 1, i -> 3, to -> 1, cried -> 1, you -> 1, tuned -> 1, around -> 1, was -> 1, there -> 1, hours -> 1, how -> 1, televised -> 1, me -> 1, not -> 1, could -> 1, were -> 1, passion -> 1, we -> 1, sat -> 1, when -> 1, like -> 1, of -> 2, and -> 1, watched -> 1, proceedings -> 1, the -> 3) of type [Any, Int]

The List(pos) is created from a file which contains huge number of words. It can be found [here](http://130.15.6.119) in the positive words section. In order to create that list I have used the below code:

`val words = """([A-Za-z])+""".r
val pos = scala.io.Source.fromFile("Positive_words.txt").getLines.drop(35).flatMap(words.findAllIn).toList`

I notice that when the list is matched with the map using either:

`val result = output.filterKeys(pos.contains)`

or

`output.foreach { x => pos.foreach { aa => if(x._1.toString() == aa) <create a new hashmap>}}`

results in something unexpected. There are some words which even though do not exist in pos are shown in the output.

Output snippet below:

> val result = output.filterKeys(pos.contains)
>
> result: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Any,Int] = Map(in -> 9, all -> 1, a -> 2, to -> 1, around -> 1, passion -> 1, like -> 1, of -> 2, the -> 3)
>   This is printing some irrelevant items which are not even a part of list = pos.

words like in, all, to are not expected.

PS: If a simple list(pos) is created WITHOUT using the above mentioned code, the output is just fine.

Comment: Your example is unclear: First, there's no value in the map that actually corresponds to any value in `pos`, so the _expected_ output here seems to be _empty_ (nothing printed); And indeed - running your code on your sample data produces no printing at all - your code works as expected. Can you clarify what the issue is with some data that actually shows the problem?

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Tzach. I have update my post , hope this time I am able to explain better. Please note that the solution that you gave works just fine if I create a simple map and list but in my case it does not work and I don't understand why when it ideally should.

Answer (score 1):

You can use map's `filterKeys` to keep only the keys that exist in the `pos` list, using `pos.contains` as the predicate:

```
val result = output.filterKeys(pos.contains)
result.foreach(println)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this might help you. But normally only primitives(boolean, int, every type with lower case beginning) should be compared with "==". All the other objects should be compared with .equals() and a String is such an object.
Maybe you just keep this in mind.

Comment: While this is true in _Java_, in Scala `==` defaults to the `.equals()` of the object.

Comment: Just now saw that even though the post clearly discusses Scala, it was tagged with `java` too - which is obviously the source of confusion here. I removed the Java tag to clarify what seems to be the OP's intention (and retracted my downvote...).

Answer (score 0):

The use of flatMap while creating the list was creating the problem.

It was resolved by using the below code instead of what I had written earlier:

`val pos = scala.io.Source.fromFile("Positive_words.txt").getLines.drop(35).toList`

Thanks.